# the maximum and minimum output voltage of op-amp

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, adc, current-measurement

my question is a bit specific, I have done the research but I got confused.

I am trying to measure the current using current sense resistor and a current sense amplifier [INA 210](http://www.ti.com/product/INA210/datasheet) . my measurements will be taken using a 5V ADC( arduino). and I will be having **5V power supply** to power up the ADC and the op-amp.

I want to measure current from 0- 0.5 amp, and lets say my op-amp gain is 100. so I have a chosen a current sense resistor of 0.1 ohm so when the current is max 0.5 amp, the voltage across the resistor will be 0.5 amp*0.1 ohm = 0.05 volt and when amplified amplified it will be 5 volt which is the full range of the op-amp.

that is okay but then I figured that the output of the op-amp will not swing to reach the supply voltage as it will reach bellow the 5 V supply voltage and it won't reach 0 volt which is my system ground.

my questions are:
1- I got confused getting the maximum and minimum output ranges and here are two pictures of the values I suspect, which one is true?

[image]

and here is the second picture:

[image]

2- second question is , if the second picture is the case, how to solve this problem? I mean this way I want be able to read the higher voltages above the op-amp range and the lower voltages bellow the other end of the op-amp output ranges

Comment: One of them is what the opamp is capable to do, and one is what you are allowed to do with its pins.

Comment: ... without damaging it. Maximum ratings: what can you safely apply externally. Electrical Characteristics: what can the IC do by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Best option will likely be to adjust the feedback resistor on your op amp so that you can accurately measure from 0-0.5A using voltage range 0.05-4.8 that the op amp is guaranteed capable of.

No amplifier that I'm aware of can operate at steady-state at or beyond it's "rails" (although there are several AC amps that can momentarily do that).

Comment: this op-amp has a fixed gain. its designed this way because this will reduce the error if normal resistors are to be used to set the gain

Comment: In that case, maybe the best option would be to get a slightly smaller value current-sense resistor, maybe 0.095 would work.

Comment: Often the inputs can go outside the rails by 150mv or so on the low end and still have normal functionality

Comment: @SabirMoglad: IN210  is a fixed gain, but there are part nos available in the same IN21x series with different gain. Or may be powering he op-amp with 5.25V can guarantee the output close to 5.0V which 0.2V less (worst case) as per specs.